# Django error: Instance of 'OneToOneField' has no 'username' member pylint(no-member)

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm new to Django and I'm learning it throw a youtube tutorial. I'm trying to build a simple Blog but I have some problem that I think could be related to python or django version.
I'm using python3.7.5 and django2.1.5.
I've created the following model which represent the user's profile which overrides the save method to enable a resize of the uploaded profile picture.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

     def __str__(self):
         return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

     def save(self):
         super().save()

         img = Image.open(self.image.path)

         if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
              output_size = (300, 300)
              img.thumbnail(output_size)
              img.save(self.image.path)
```

From this I get a few errors, for example in **str** method from this line:

```
return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

I get this error:

```
Instance of 'OneToOneField' has no 'username' memberpylint(no-member)
```

And I get similar error every time I use the self.
Can anyone help me?

EDIT:
Probably is a problem with vscode because if I try to print:

```
   self.user.username
```

It works fine, anyone had he same problem before?

Comment: Try this `return '{}{}'.format(self.user,' Profile')`

Comment: I think that could be a problem of vscode because the IDE tell me that there is no username for OneToOneField but if I try to print self.user.username it works fine.

Comment: Yes, it may be linter issue. You can disable some warnings and errors depending on your linter in vscode settings.

Comment: But is very strange, I've a lot of errors but when I run the application everything work fine. Do you use vscode to implement django application?

Comment: Yes I use VS code for django, I know this problem. You must check your linter settings in vscode. Install and change your linter to pylint or flake8.

Comment: If you are getting so many errors and warning then set following in VS code settings>select interpreter and set it's value to `path_to_your_virtual_environment\Scripts\python.exe` this should solve your problem. Even you can set it manually by creating `.vscode` directory at root of project and then creating `settings.json` inside .vscode directory and then setting interpreter property as  `{ "python.pythonpath" : "path_to_your_virtual_environment/Scripts/python.exe" }`. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to k33da_lets_debug I found out it was a problem with vscode setting, I changed my linter from pylint to flake8 and now the errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an issue with relation with user model.

Lets make the relation something like this -

models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: I've already tried changing it but I still have the same problem. If it can help you this is the repo with the code I'm following: https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Django_Blog/09-Update-User-Profile/django_project
Is strange because he hasn't this problem at all

Comment: lets debug this -  by adding the below code.

 def __str__(self):
    print(self.user)
    vars(self.user)
    return "Testing {}".format(self.image)

Comment: Okay, I tried and I get a really weird behaviour, vscode still shows me the error but the application works fine.
In any case from the print I get what is expected, the name of the user and the name of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow k33da_lets_debug's suggestion, but, it didn't solve my problem. However, I finally got a solution by using the 'disable linting' option in the Python: select Linter menu. This menu can be accessed by pressing ctrl+shift+p or command+shift+p. That's it.